# pointer string is not taking input in C programming

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int w,p;
   char *name[1000];
   for(w=0; p!=2; w++)
   {
      printf("Add a name: ");
      gets(name[w]);
      printf("Want to add another one?\n1 for yes\n2 for no\n");
      scanf("%d",&p);
   }
}
```

This code is not working. If I write:
     char *name[3]={"Mitchell Johnson", "Mitchell Starc", "Steven Smith"};
then it works. but i want to take strings as input. dont want to define it.
 But console box stops working after taking 1 string input. How to do it right? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: [why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: You should explain what is your objective: store many strings or overwrite a single buffer with different strings?

Comment: @LPs `p<=2` would continue looping when the user enters `2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
   int w = 0;
   int ret = 0;
   int p = 1;
   char line[1024];
   char **tab = (char**)malloc(1000*sizeof(char*));
   for(w=0; p==1; w++)
   {
      printf("Add a name: ");
      ret = read(0, &line, 1024);
      line[ret] = 0;
      printf(line);
      tab[w] = strdup(line);
      printf("Want to add another one?\n1 for yes\n2 for no\n");
      scanf("%d",&p);
   }
}
```

This should do what you want. But it's pretty ugly.

Comment: thanks, it works!! but i am not getting how this thing works. can make it simpler? i am very beginner in C programming. please. can u make my code work (the one that i included in question) by doing some changes?

Comment: @Adder yes, that why i said it's ugly.

About the code it is pretty simple:
First I create everything i will need and initialize it (very important !).
The char line[1024] is just a buffer in wich I will write the line written.
The char **tab is an array in wich we copy the last line at the end (which is w).
You can find the read function in man 2 or somewhere on the web, it returns the number of char read. That is why I add a 0 after the last char with line[ret] = 0;
And tab[w] = strdup(line) is just to allocate memory and copy the string line at the position w in the array.

Comment: By the way, if you type a string which countains more than 1024 char it will be truncated and if you enter more than 1000 lines, it will probably crash. To avoid that you need to create a new array of string which is bigger than the previous and copy the previous in the new one and use the new one.

Comment: thank you. now i started getting it

Answer (score 0):

You forget to allocate memory for the string read:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int w,p=0;
   char *name[1000];
   char line[1024];
   for(w=0; p!=2; w++)
   {
      printf("Add a name: ");
      fgets(line, 1024,stdin);
      name[w]= malloc(strlen(line)+1);  // add this
      strcpy(name[w], line);            // add this
      printf("Want to add another one?\n1 for yes\n2 for no\n");
      scanf("%d",&p);
   }
}
```

Note that you must initialize `p`; it could already be 2.

Comment: OK, disclaimer: "I didn't report other bugs (though I can see a few)"

Comment: Even better would be to use fgets instead of gets.

Comment: sorry that didn't work.....please can you check? i badly need the solution for my project

Comment: Jake, use a debugger. And I am under the impression that your "project" is homework. Learning to use a debugger will teach you a lot. And read the documentation of scanf.

Comment: I was referring to gets ... ;)